# Obtener datos de usuario logueado desde base de datos C# Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, identity

Quiero obtener un dato de los usuarios logueados utilizando User.Identity mediante una consulta:

```
var nombre = (from s in db.AspNetUsers
                         where s.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                         select s.Nombre).ToString();
```

Para que ese dato sea almacenado en un metodo Create:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

                registro.Nombre= nombre.ToString();
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Me arroja el siguiente error:

*System.NotSupportedException: 'No se admite el tipo de nodo de la expresión LINQ 'ArrayIndex' en LINQ to Entities.'*

Mas que nada quiero poder obtener este dato del usuario que esta logueado y se almacene en otra tabla, quiza no sea la forma de correcta de hacerlo, si alguien puede ayudarme de favor.

Comment: no entiendo bien tu cuestionamiento, dire esto con temor a equivocarme pero no puedes obtener todos los datos del usuario logueado de esa manera, yo los obtengo usando DirectoryServices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segun lo que veo estas intentando convertir una consulta en `toString()`, cuando todavia no la has ejecutado.

```
var nombre = (from s in db.AspNetUsers
                     where s.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                     select s.Nombre).FirtsOrDefault();
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, habia probado con toList() y con toString() y me guardaba la consulta, ya usando FirstOrDefault() me guarda el resultado de la consulta que es lo que queria, muchas gracias, te doy el check verde. Saludos.

Comment: Si ejecutas con ToList(), despues deberias recorrer ese resultado con un foreach o con una expresion lambda de linq.